# Replacement for GetInput() SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

I was going to use

```
GetInput()
```

for this code but I have to use something different instead. pollEvent gives me these errors:

```
error C2664: 'sf::Window::pollEvent' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'sf::Event &'
error C2664: 'sf::Window::pollEvent' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'sf::Event &'
```

The code is:

```
int x = camera->GetPosition().x + window->pollEvent(sf::Mouse::getPosition().x);
int y = camera->GetPosition().y + window->pollEvent(sf::Mouse::getPosition().y);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? I see your code, but I don't understand what it's trying to accomplish

Comment: Basically I want to move the camera to wherever the mouse is clicked. This means I need to get the position of the mouse inside the camera.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sf::Window::pollEvent()`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Window.php#a338e996585faf82e93069858e3b531b7) takes an argument of type `Event& event`, but you're trying to pass `sf::Mouse::getPosition().x`/`y`. I have no clue why you're calling `window->pollEvent()` at all, and from what it looks like you're trying to do, you can just remove the function call and add `sf::Mouse::getPosition().x`/`y` directly.

**Edit:** Based on your comment, it looks like you want to something more like this:

```
sf::Event event;
while (window->pollEvent(event)) // Be sure to put this in your main event loop
{
    if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
    {
        int x = camera->GetPosition().x + event.mouseButton.x;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an unhandled exception now. I'll fix that later.